# How to retrieve the data from mongodb in json format using c# entity framework

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, entity-framework

I am retrieving the data from mongodb.it is coming as bson document.

when i am converting it to json it throws system out of memory exception because of bulk data (>100 000) is coming from mongodb.

Is it possible to retrieve the data from mongodb in json format directly?

[image: SystemOutOfMemoryExceptionScreenShot]

```
 public object getFrequencyQuestionData1(int id)
{
    var StudyId = (from ST in _context.Study_Team
                   where ST.Emp_Id == id
                   select (ST.Study_Id).ToString()).ToList();
    var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
    MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("FormDataBase");
    MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("FrequencyQuestionForm");
    var array = new BsonArray(StudyId.ToArray());
    var query = Query.In("data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Study_Id", array);                   
    var myLists = collection.Find(query);           
    myLists.SetFields(Fields.Include("_id","data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Study_Id", "data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Study_Name", "data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Volunteer_Id", "data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Form_Id","data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Form_Name", "data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Status", "data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Group_Id", "data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Visit_No","data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Created_Emp_Id", "data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Updated_Emp_Id"));
    var items = myLists.ToList();
    string document = items.ToJson();
    JToken token = JToken.Parse(document);
    var jObject = JObject.FromObject(new { formdata = token });
    JArray sizes = (JArray)jObject["formdata"];
    ArrayList SplittedData = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizes.Count(); i++)
    {
        JValue _id = (JValue)sizes[i]["_id"];
        JObject sampledata = (JObject)sizes[i]["data"];
        JArray sampledata2 = (JArray)sampledata["formList"];
        JArray sampledata3 = (JArray)sampledata2[0]["IdentificationDetails"];
        sampledata3[0]["id"] = _id;
        int? Visit_No = (int?)sampledata3[0]["Visit_No"];
        int? Group_Id = (int?)sampledata3[0]["Group_Id"];
        int? Study_Id = (int?)sampledata3[0]["Study_Id"];
        int? Form_Id = (int?)sampledata3[0]["Form_Id"];
        int CreatedEmp_Id =(int)sampledata3[0]["Created_Emp_Id"];
        var Visit_No1 = (from SS in _context.Study_Schedule
                         join SV in _context.Study_Visits
                         on new { SS.Study_Id, SS.Visit_No } equals
                            new { SV.Study_Id, SV.Visit_No }
                         //on SS.Study_Id equals SV.Study_Id && SS.Visit_No equals SV.Visit_No
                         where SS.Study_Id == Study_Id && SS.Visit_No == Visit_No && SS.Form_Id == Form_Id
                         select SV.Visit_Description).FirstOrDefault();
        var Created_Emp_Id = (from US in _context.User
                              where US.Emp_Id == CreatedEmp_Id
                              select US.Emp_Name).FirstOrDefault();

        sampledata3[0]["Created_Emp_Id"] = Created_Emp_Id;
        if (Group_Id == null)
        {
            sampledata3[0]["Diet_Group"] = "";
        }
        else
        {
            var StudyGroup = (from SG in _context.Study_Group
                              where SG.Group_Id == Group_Id
                              select new
                              {
                                  Group_Description = SG.Group_Description,
                              }).FirstOrDefault();
            if (StudyGroup == null)
            {
                sampledata3[0]["Diet_Group"] = "";
            }
            else
            {
                sampledata3[0]["Diet_Group"] = StudyGroup.Group_Description.ToString();
            }
        }
        sampledata3[0]["Visit"] = Visit_No1;
        sampledata3[0]["Created_Emp_Id"] = Created_Emp_Id;
        var  sampledata4 =  (JObject)sampledata3[0];
        SplittedData.Add(sampledata4);
    }
    var jObject1 = JObject.FromObject(new { formdata = SplittedData});
    return jObject1;
}
```